# How to force Ghostscript to convert PDF to monochrome bitmap using CMYK colors instead of RGB?

Tags: rgb, ghostscript, cmyk

I have a PDF file containing black text specified with CMYK color of 0,0,0,100.  When I convert this to "bmpmono" using ghostscript, it interprets this as not 100% black.  I discovered that CMYK 0,0,0,100 actually converts to RGB of around 36,32,33 and not 0,0,0 as I had expected (but is explained [here](https://underthemoonlight.ca/2020/03/07/cmyk-black-vs-rgb-black-whats-the-difference/)).

I believe what's happening is ghostscript is converting the CMYK to RGB and then to monochrome, so I end up with non-fully-black text.  Is there a way to force ghostscript to stick with the CMYK and directly convert to monochrome to keep the 100% black?

Here is my command:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bmpmono -dBATCH -dDEVICERESOLUTION=200 -sOutputFile=testout.bmp -f source.pdf
```

Comment: It'll be the colour management. I doubt it is converting CMYK->RGB->grey, I would imagine the actual path is CMYK->ICC XYZ->Grey which will involve two profiles creating a profile link. One to take CMYK and produce XYZ and another to take XYZ and produce Grey. The defaults are probably ghostpdl/iccprofiles/default_cmyk.icc and default_gray.icc. You can change the profiles being used on the command line, it's up to you to get a pair of profiles that map the way you want. Possibly the BlackPoint is important,. While the URL you quote is useful, I don't think it is relevant here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Can you direct me to a link I can use to guide me through the profile creation process?  Also, is there a way to verify which profile is being used by ghostscript so I can know if I successfully change it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, ICC profiles are not my area of expertise. The command line switches for using different profiles are documented here https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.56.1/Use.htm#ICC_color_parameters and there's a PDF file on colour management included in the documentation in ghostpdl/doc/GS9_Color_Management.pdf From that it looks to me like you want -sDefaultCMYKProfile= and -sOutputICCProfile= If you get a CMYK and Gray profile which map through that should work I think (but I am not an expert on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GS will do a conversion from CMYK to Gray through the defined ICC profiles.  There are darker CMYK values that exist (for GS's defined CMYK source profile -- and for most) compared to a CMYK value of [0 0 0 100]  So, [0 0 0 100] ends up being mapped to something that is not the darkest in the Gray output space.

A couple options would be to try

-dUseFastColor

which will avoid the use of ICC profiles for color mapping and use old school 255-X with UCR/BG type mappings.

Another option is to use

-dBlackText=true

This will force all text components (except for Type 3 fonts) to be filled (or stroked) with a gray value of 0 which should map to 0 for the bmpmono device.

Comment: The fast color option seemed to work for my needs.  Cheers!